# react-i18next page reload occurs missingKeyHandler error

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-i18next

If I reload a page, it throws me an missingKeyHandler error.
This is my i18n config.

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import HttpApi from "i18next-http-backend";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    lng: "en",
    ns: ["common"],
    preload: ["en"],
    defaultNS: "common",
    partialBundledLanguages: true,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: "./locales/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json",
      crossDomain: true,
    },
    saveMissing: true,
    missingKeyHandler: (lng, ns, key) => {
      throw new Error(`Missing i18n key ${[lng].flat().join(",")}:${ns}:${key}`);
    }
  });

 export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `allowMultiLoading:false` to backend config & change `loadPath` did the trick for me.

```
i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    ...
    backend: {
      loadPath: "/locales/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json",
      allowMultiLoading: false,
      ...
    },
    saveMissing: false,
    ...
  });
```